# Error while reading XLS file with apache poi libraries: "No UNDO/REDO support for w3c.dom!!"

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read xlsx/xls file. while reading the file I am getting "No UNDO/REDO support for w3c.dom!!"

This is code I am using:

```
 try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(xlsPath);) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
    }
```

Dependencies added in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is error log which I am getting:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:59)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No UNDO/REDO support for w3c.dom!!
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBaseUndo.getDomNode(XmlObjectBaseUndo.java:510)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:114)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.<init>(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:102
```

)

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?

Comment: After updating Apache POI to 4.0.0, I am getting different error.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RAW_XML_FILE_HEADER
 at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.<clinit>(FileMagic.java:45)

Comment: You need to remove the old jars, that error indicates you still have old Apache POI jars on your classpath

Comment: I updated the jar and degraded too, I tried with both lower version (3.17) and updated version 4.0.1. Issue is still there.

Comment: could you try adding https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.0 to your classpath? - it looks like you have an unusual XML DOM parser in your environment.

Comment: and org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBaseUndo in your stacktrace is not a class I can find - could you try a recent xmlbeans jar like 3.1.0?

Comment: No luck, still the same problem

Comment: Make sure you remove the old jars on your classpath. You might not think they are there, but the errors indicate you accidentally have others!